# use add_row to programmatically add an entry to a flexible content field in advanced custom fields for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Wondering how to use add_rows (or something similar) to add an entry to a flexible content field programmatically. On ACF's website they mention add_rows can be used to add a row to a flexible content field https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/ but they give no examples how to do it with a flexible content field; only with a repeater field. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `add_row( $selector, $value, $post_id )` This function will add a new row of data to an existing repeater field field value.

$selector: (required) The parent field name or key

$value: (required) The new value to append

$post_id: (optional) The post ID of which the value is saved to. Defaults to current post
Return

Below is the example that how you can add `image` filed with multiple values

```
<?php 

$row = array(
    'image' => 123,
    'alt'   => 'Another great sunset',
    'link'  => 'http://website.com'
);

$i = add_row('images', $row);

?>
```

To Add repeater field in flexible content you should use below code :

```
<?php 
$field_key = "flexible_content_field_key";
$value = array(
    array( "sub_field_1" => "Foo1", "sub_field_2" => "Bar1", "acf_fc_layout" => "layout_1_name" ),
    array( "sub_field_x" => "Foo2", "sub_field_y" => "Bar2", "acf_fc_layout" => "layout_2_name" )
);
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );

?>
```

Here `acf_fc_layout` is used to add sub fields for image here `image` is flexible content field key where in your case there will be your flexible content key.

Comment: Yes I've seen this example but this is an example for a repeater field, not a flexible content field...like I mentioned in the OP. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: I have updated the answer for add repeater fields in flexible content fields

Comment: That's what's up! You're my hero!

Comment: fwiw I reached out to ACF support and they told me that add_rows is actually NOT supported for flexible content fields despite what their site says at this current time. Support also mentioned this is on the developer's todo list.